# Prospective job postponed by employer

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search, email

Recently I went through interview process (3) for a job I really wanted.  I receive an email follow up today from the employer, stating that they’ve decided to put the position on hold for now, and hope I can be contacted in the future when they continue with the hiring process at the end of the year.

What is the best way to respond?

I really want the job even if that means waiting 6 months. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any indication of why the position was put on hold, or when a search would be resumed?

Comment: They just mentioned in the email "that the role and interview process is on hold until later this year". And they asked "if they could reach back once they resume the interview process."

Answer (score 9):

> *I really want the job even if that means waiting 6 months.*

So do that. The company informed that they are putting the *position* on hold, not you or your application. There's nothing much you can do from your side now.

You can respond them by thanking them for the opportunity, something like

> *"Thanks for allowing me the opportunity to interview with your organization. I'll be looking forward to resume the communication once the position becomes available in future. Thanks."*

That being said, I'd not be relying on them to get back, the message you received may very well be a simple rejection message, disguised as the postponing message, to encourage applicants to re-apply after a certain period of time. If you need a change of job, keep looking elsewhere. In case this company contacts you in future, you ca take the call at that point - but if I were you, I would not have relied on them getting back alone.

Comment: I would recommend that if you really want the job, be more positive than what Sourav recommends. His phraseology could easily be mistaken for simple politeness. I recommend something like: "I was really excited by the prospect of working in this role, and I sincerely hope that that you will contact me when the position does become open, when I will be very open to considering an offer."

Comment: @DJClayworth There's no harm in being more positive, but what you're assuming here is, the next time, if, comes, it'll skip the interview process - which is very unlikely to be true. I'd say, at max, expect a callback, but do not expect them to literally "resume" the process - that's a far-fetched theory, not likely to be a reality.

Comment: You make a good point. But the important thing is to communicate that you really do want the job, and that you are not just being polite.

Comment: @DJClayworth In my experience, whether you want a job or not is of lesser importance, the main factor is whether you are suitable for the job or not - showing eagerness for the job does not enhance the later. YMMV.

Comment: I've been in this situation from an employer's point of view. You are right that he will not be offered the job unless they are a good candidate. But even then there may be an assumption, several months later, that the candidate will have found another job and won't want to leave it *unless they have expressed some enthusiasm for this particular job*. Expressing that enthusiasm is the best way of maximising your chances that they really will contact you again.

Comment: @DJClayworth Agree. Let me sum it up: ***Hope for the best (hope to get a call back), plan for the worst (search for other opportunities.)***

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. It really helped.  Unfortunately in this position we feel very vulnerable and having supportive feedback assisted in a professional response.

Comment: This was my email response::      Thank you again for allowing me the opportunity to interview with you and Rebecca.  I appreciated visiting the —— offices, and getting a better understanding of the expectations in the role as ——.  I am glad that I am still considered a strong candidate for this role.  I was really excited by the prospect of working with you both, and I sincerely hope that you will contact me when you continue the interview process.  Please reach out to me once the position becomes available in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Did you receive a formal offer with a start date far in the future? If not, I would **work under the assumption that the employment opportunity is no longer available.**

“On hold” could mean many things, but it at least tells you that **the company has ceased searching for candidates for the role.**  They may have found another way to organize a team so that the role is not needed, or the team may have just found a way to work with one fewer team members (or any other possible explanation).

Stay in touch with the recruiter and the manager in case they ever do resume a search for the role. You could even ask about other roles at the same organization. But if you’re looking for a new opportunity, I wouldn’t hold out hope for this one.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to respond?

Thank them for their time and let them know they are free to contact you when they continue the hiring process.

That being said, if you're looking for new work I would not recommend sitting and waiting for 6 months for any specific company.  This company may contact you, they may not.  Even if they do contact you, there is no guarantee that they will offer you the position.

I would continue to apply to and interview with other companies.  Who knows, one of them may be better for you than this company and may actually offer you a position.

Comment: Yes. I will continue seeking. Thanks!